# 2019, Chrome 76, approach to autocomplete off

Tags: forms, google-chrome, autocomplete, street-address

There are are few posts out there about this. You spend hours going through each answer, testing, reading comments, to find that there is no solution. What have you done in 2019, Chrome 76, that works?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Update, January 2020:** It appears that as of Chrome 79, Autocomplete (as defined here) no longer treats `autocomplete="some-unrecognised-value"` as equal to `autocomplete="on"`, so `autocomplete="nope"` or similar is now effective at disabling both Autocomplete and Autofill.

**Update, April 2020:** They changed it again. As of Chrome 81, `autocomplete="some-unrecognised-value"` is no longer effective at disabling the Autocomplete mechanism. However, Autofill now seems to be a lot more conservative than it was before - it still doesn't follow the spec (a field with `name="email"` and `autocomplete="off"` will still receive Autofill suggestions) but it doesn't offer up spurious address fragments on random form fields. My recommendation right now would therefore be to use `autocomplete="off"`. If you want to do that on a field named `email`, you're probably out of luck though :-(

---

*TL,DR: There appears to be no setting for the `autocomplete` attribute that will reliably turn off all autocomplete dropdowns. However, the circumstances that have led to this are quite convoluted and worth documenting, to hopefully clear up the masses of conflicting advice...*

There are two distinct mechanisms present in current (76.0.3809.132) versions of Chrome, which we'll refer to as Autofill and Autocomplete (not necessarily their official names):

## Autofill

[image: Autofill example: a dropdown showing two postcodes and a "Manage addresses..." option]

The Autofill feature attempts to fill in forms using the address information stored in your browser settings. It can be identified by the "Manage addresses..." option (or similar) at the bottom of the dropdown. This feature does not honour `autocomplete="off"` or `autocomplete="false"`, as a deliberate decision on the part of the Chrome developers.

In [a statement outlining this decision](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164), zkoch offered this workaround:

> In cases where you really want to disable autofill, our suggestion at
>   this point is to utilize the autocomplete attribute to give valid,
>   semantic meaning to your fields. If we encounter an autocomplete
>   attribute that we don't recognize, we won't try and fill it.
>
> As an example, if you have an address input field in your CRM tool
>   that you don't want Chrome to Autofill, you can give it semantic
>   meaning that makes sense relative to what you're asking for: e.g.
>   autocomplete="new-user-street-address".  If Chrome encounters that, it
>   won't try and autofill the field.

This is the basis of attempted solutions such as `autocomplete="nope"`; the Autofill mechanism will skip any fields with `autocomplete` attribute values it doesn't recognise.

The code that implements this decision, for the record: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/78.0.3903.1/components/autofill/core/browser/form_structure.cc#1218

## Autocomplete

[image: Autocomplete example: a dropdown showing a previously submitted form value]

The Autocomplete feature provides a dropdown of previously-submitted values from this form field. This dropdown does not have a "Manage addresses..." option. Autocomplete *does* honour the `autocomplete="off"` or `autocomplete="false"` attribute; any other value (including 'invalid' ones such as `autocomplete="nope"`) will leave it enabled.

## Conclusion

Autocompletion dropdowns cannot be turned off through the `autocomplete` dropdown; any value that disables Autofill will leave Autocomplete enabled, and vice versa. Anyone who thinks they've found a working solution (either through `autocomplete` or some other method such as CSS hacks) should check that it works against *both* mechanisms.

Unfortunately it's probably going to be an uphill struggle to convince Chrome's developers that this is broken. The developers of Autofill apparently believe that they made a calculated decision to break `autocomplete="off"` while offering web developers an alternative; that alternative is broken, for more subtle reasons than they realise. From their perspective, the resulting [howls of protest](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466) are coming from disgruntled developers too lazy to jump through one little hoop and update their `autocomplete="off"` attributes. In all the noise, the message isn't getting through: the hoop is broken.

Comment: autocomplete="nope" etc doesn't seem to work on Chrome 80, for autofill

Comment: This is the best explanation for this I've ever read, it is much much clearer now. Thank you very much.

Comment: "jump through one little hoop and update their autocomplete="off".... what hoop is that?   We've got chrome autocomplete trying to get the user to pick a saved payment method to put in inputs having nothing to do with payment methods.

Comment: @Marz The hoop in question was 'give it semantic meaning that makes sense relative to what you're asking for: e.g. autocomplete="new-user-street-address"'. But it doesn't work (or didn't in 2019) - that's the point I was making here.

Answer (score 22):

Try using `type="search"` instead of "text" for your input field, I've done this several time and it works for me.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer for ages... nope, false-- nothing worked but this did. As of Nov 4, 2019

Comment: I'm glad it works. I also have been looking too long for a solution. Hope from Google Chrome team will take developers remarks that have been rolling for years now.

Comment: This works on chrome 78 | macos 10.13. let's see how much time takes for chrome responsibles to 'fix' this... :-S

Comment: Working on 2021/02/23. I was looking for many solutions and finally this works.

Comment: Not useful for a case like type="tel".

Answer (score 8):

***As of Dec 6, 2019, with Chrome v78.x***

Standard methods like `autocomplete="off"` are now working almost fine for the latest versions of Chrome. Except for this one:

[image: Chrome's auto-completion list for Manage Addresses]

This thing is a real bummer because it doesn't only disrespect the standard/non-standard values like `"nope"` but there's literally no way to turn this off unless the input is not even remotely related with *"addressy"* terms.

How on earth we could possibly display address-related input fields without using address-related words? **Here comes the easiest solution ever.**

- Make sure the input element's `name` and `id` don't include any address-related terms. Attributes like `id="input-street"` or `name="destination-zip"` are big no-no.
- **This is the most crucial part:** If you are required to use any human-readable address terms for the text input or any of its adjacent elements, insert the "invisible" **zero width joiner (`&zwnj;`)** between the letters of the said term. In this way, we can fool the AI capability of Chrome and bypass its strict autocompletion behavior.

**Some working examples:**

```html
<input id="input-stret" placeholder="S&zwnj;treet" autocomplete="off">

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="product-addres">Product A&zwnj;ddress</label>
  <input name="addres" id="product-addres" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

And there you go. No more pesky menus for managing addresses, nor any regular autocompletion menus.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 80 now. The null character worked just fine for me (in every word in the `<label>`) with no `name` or `id` attributes in the `<input>`. The hard part came during two-way binding in Angular (8). We had to move this:

`<label>{{ foo }}</label>`

to this:

`<label [innerHTML]="foo"></label>`

and change the null char in `foo` to `&#8205;`:

`public const foo: string = 'Fi&#8205;rst Na&#8205;me';`

As the null character (mentioned above) showed up as an unknown character when rendered in HTML.

I also used `autocomplete="off"` for every `<input>` and `<form>`.

Comment: For some reason, the character &#0; wasn't working.
I used &zwnj; instead and it worked like a charm.
Also replacing each name / id from ADDRESS to ADDRES_S with just an underscore, it works to fool chrome.
Didn't test on other browsers.

Comment: @Kilowog I recognize the limitations of using the null character. Updated my answer for the zero-width joiner.

Comment: Feb 2021: If I use autocomplete="off" and don't use any descriptive words in the label for the field (e.g. "Fill in your address" etc) then it works (i.e. doesn't try to autofill/autocomplete with saved addresses)

Comment: @ScottDecker I am not being nit-picky but in terms of UX, is it possible to create an address-related field without using the descriptive words like "address"?

Comment: @FilipVeličković Ha.  Totally valid.  One potential way would be what I have done: a placeholder in the input which says "Enter address here".  That usage doesn't seem to trigger the auto-complete/auto-fill for some reason.

Comment: We already have a character hack in the label name, and still no dice

Answer (score 3):

As [gasman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810447/8642105) explains, both the `autofill` and `autocomplete` features must be disabled, which doesn't seem possible on a single input.
The only working solution I've found is to setting `autocomplete="off"` on the input and add hidden fake inputs before the real input that fool `autofill`, like so:

```
<input name="Fake_Username" id="Fake_Username" type="text" style="display:none">
<input name="Fake_Password" id="Fake_Password" type="password" style="display:none">
<input name="NameInput" id="NameInput" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I think the question is about chrome feature its not about the input fields in HTML form.

Answer (score 3):

*** This answer is incorrect. I've published a better (but uglier) solution as a new answer and kept this answer since some parts may still be useful. If that's not how to deal with incorrect answers on stackoverflow, feel free to delete this one ***

Consider using autocomplete=<nonce>, where <nonce> is unique per field and across page loads.

For example, if a field is the N-th field created after the page was requested at timestamp TS, its <nonce> can be chosen to be nope_<TS>_<N>.

Effect on autocomplete: since <nonce> is a custom value for autocomplete, chromium does not activate the autocomplete function (see [form_structure.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/78.0.3903.1/components/autofill/core/browser/form_structure.cc)).

Effect on autofill: chromium recognizes a field by comparing its fingerprint with those of earlier encountered fields (see [form_field_data.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/78.0.3903.1/components/autofill/core/common/form_field_data.cc)). If recognized it may offer a list of remembered values. The fingerprints contain the value of the autocomplete attribute. Since no two nonces are equal, no field is recognized.

Notes:

- The terms autocomplete and autofill as used here are swapped compared to gasman's reply.
- All fields should be created dynamically on the client-side (unless you are willing to not have the page cached).

Comment: Nice idea, but it isn't working for me on Chrome 77.0.3865.90 when I test it on https://find-postgraduate-teacher-training.education.gov.uk/ - setting the postcode field to `autocomplete="nope_20191017_123"` in the DOM inspector is still giving suggestions remembered from previous submissions (that were made with a different autocomplete value). I can see that form_field_data.cc is indeed differentiating fields based on `autocomplete_attribute` though - perhaps it's already been normalised to true/false at that point?

Comment: I my test-cases (Chrome 78) I did get rid of the popups except (I noticed only yesterday) for fields having type="password". This is annoying since it concerns passwords handed out by an admin to other users. It should not have done so according to the idea I posted so there definitely is something more to it. I have considered normalization but I find it unlikely and couldn't find any such code. I'm still looking for the places where == operator is used. I'll post back when I've investigated more (PS. what happens for you if you randomize another innocent  attribute?)

Comment: Found a solution for your form after reading [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/autofill/core/browser/autocomplete_history_manager.cc#354). Good news: used the randomization-approach on a copy of your form to get rid of the suggestions. Bad news: similar approach, but more obtrusive/hacky. I'll have to edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

```html
autocomplete="new-password"
```

This is a hint, which browsers are not required to comply with. However modern browsers have stopped autofilling `<input>` elements with `autocomplete="new-password"` for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

*Disabling autofill:*
Set autocomplete attribute to a non-standard value, e.g. "nope".

*Disabling autocomplete:*
The autocomplete function stores field names and their values when a form is submitted.
There's (almost, see note 1) nothing sensible to be done to prevent storage except setting autocomplete to "off"/"false" (see [why](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/autofill/core/browser/autocomplete_history_manager.cc#354)).
Unfortunately that's not an option as it would enable autofill.

However it's possible to prevent retrieval of previous values by appending "!<nonce>" to the field names, where <nonce> is unique per page load
(thus making field names unrecognizable).

On the client side this can be achieved by something like the following line of javascript (upon page load):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'))
   .forEach(function(elt) { elt.name += '!' + new Date().getTime(); });
```

On the server side the part (if any) starting at "!" should be dropped from variable names (upon receiving post variables).

PS: this answer is an erratum to my earlier solution which is cleaner but wasn't sufficiently tested and - as gasman rightly pointed out - doesn't work for ordinary forms. This new solution was tested on Chrome Canary 79, does work, has relatively small impact and degrades nicely. Still, I feel guilty about publishing this hack and will feel even more guilty if I ever encounter it in real forms. It is *very* dirty.

Note 1: the only way to prevent storage that *does* make sense is to not set the name attribute in the first place (or to unset it), which necessitates  intercepting the submit event to post the data "manually" (using XMLHttpRequest). Since the question is about forms and this strategy bypasses the traditional form-mechanism I've not elaborated on that approach. It's a nicer solution though.

---

Addendum: I decided to follow up on note 1 since I really dislike having a non-localized solution. Here's a localized version in vanilla JS that limits all impact to a single spot on the client side. Append it as a script to the document body or put it in the onload handler of the document.

```
function disableInputSuggestions(form) { // note: code uses ECMA5 features 
    // tweak the inputs of form 
    var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(form.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'));
    var nonce = Date.now();
    inputs.forEach(function(input, i) { 
        input.autocomplete = 'nope'; // prevent autocomplete
        input.originalName = input.name || input.id; // to not let this code break form handling of inputs without names (browsers fallback to the id in that case)
        input.name = nonce + '_' + i; // prevent autofill (if you're willing to eliminate all input ids first, then clear the name instead)
    });
    // replace the default submit handler by a custom one 
    form.onsubmit = function(ev) {
        // get the form data using the original variable names
        var formData = new FormData();
        inputs.forEach(function(input) { formData.set(input.originalName, input.value); });
        // submit the form data using XMLHttpRequest (alternatively, use a helper form or temporarily undo the tweaks to form) 
        var submitter = new XMLHttpRequest();
        submitter.open(form.getAttribute('method'), form.getAttribute('action'));
        submitter.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(submitter.readyState == 4 && submitter.status == 200) {
                // handle the server response, here assuming the default form.target = "_self"  
                document.open();
                document.write(submitter.responseText);
                document.close();
            }
        }
        submitter.send(formData);
        return false; // prevent submitting form
    }; 
}
disableInputSuggestions(document.forms.myForm); // assumed: the form has id = myForm
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Chrome 91**

*You need to use a random value*, meaning a value that will change each time you load the page.

From the tests that I did, chrome seems to remember any attribute value that it already encountered and will suggest the last seen value for that attribute value the next time. So, if you put autocomplete="nope", chrome will remember that autocomplete="nope" is equal to the last value that you put in autocomplete="nope".

By using a unique random value that chrome has never seen, it won't suggest anything because it has never seen that value.

**PHP 7 Example**

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="<?= bin2hex(random_bytes(10)) ?>" />
```

**Limitations**

It seems to work on address fields but it has no effect on login fields. I haven't tested with credit card fields.

Comment: It's sad that this is now necessary. I just want it to stop overlapping my custom autocomplete. I won't be advising this browser to anyone anymore. Thanks for the solution

Comment: In chrome 92 I have to use the random autocomplete value AND remove the name and id. It is possible randomizing the name and id fields would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome version 81.

For me, when input type is TEL, EMAIL or SEARCH, it WORKS with autocomplete='disabled'.
When input type is NUMBER, it WORKS with autocomplete='off'.

But when input type is TEXT .. it may works with autocomplete='off'. If not, it will do with autocomplete='disabled'.

You can try this, perhaps it will work for you (it works in 95% of cases for me) :

```
// Désactivation de l'autocomplete des input text
function setAutocomplete(val) {
    var E = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < E.length ; i++) {
        if (E[i].name == 'txt_nom') { console.log('txt_nom', E[i]); }
        var type = E[i].type.toUpperCase();
        if (E[i].autocomplete != '') { continue; }
        if (type == 'HIDDEN') {
            //
        } else if (type == 'NUMBER') {
            E[i].autocomplete = 'off';
        } else if ((type == 'TEL') || (type == 'EMAIL') || (type == 'SEARCH')) {
            E[i].autocomplete = 'disabled';
        } else {
            E[i].autocomplete = val;
        }
    }
}

// Exécution de diverses fonctions à la fin de chaque chargement
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Désactivation de l'autocomplete des input text
    setAutocomplete('off');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, I used this little trick and it worked until now (September 2020). i hope this works for a lot of people

```
--HTML--
<input type="text" name="example" autocomplete="off">
    
--Javascript--
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[autocomplete="off"]');
elements.forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    element.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
    setTimeout(() => {
        element.removeAttribute("readonly");
    }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a small jQuery plugin that disables any type of autocomplete feature from any browser

It is made to be used on the form tag, it takes few parameters and can be nested with other jQuery methods.

```
$('#login_form').randomizeFormFields();
```

It transforms this:

```
<form id="login_form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="password" name="secret">
</form>
```

Into this:

```
<form id="login_form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="yQoiFZkCrzwWXN3WWgM8Jblby">
  <input type="password" name="ono1qamA9CzrH4tW2COoRtFKI">
</form>
```

It preserves the original names upon submit

```
// returned post (php example)
array(2) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(16) "email@domain.com"
  ["secret"]=>
  string(19) "supersecretpassword"
}
```

https://github.com/cicerogeorge/randomize-form-fields

Please fork it if you have ideas

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with autocomplete = "off" and autocomplete = "nope" for EmailId textbox in html form but it is not working for Google Chrome. So I tried with below changes that worked for me.

```
<input type="email" class="tbx-input" name="Email" style="display:none;">

<input type="email" class="tbx-input" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder=" " required autocomplete="nope">
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt get any of these suggestions to work... so I just made my input a textarea, made cols="1" and disabled adjusting the space.

<textarea style="resize: none;" type='search' class="form-control" rows="1" cols="50" .... >

No more suggestions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

```
autocomplete='nope'
```

This is the current working solution for Chrome 76.

Comment: This is working for me in production on Chrome 76.0.3809.100. Maybe there's another confounding factor? If you post your code, it might be easier to help.

Comment: As per my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810447/1853523 , this disables Chrome's Autofill mechanism, but not Autocomplete.